# Angular2 Get reference to Material MdMenu created in ngFor

Tags: angular, angular-material

**What I am trying to accomplish**

I am trying to dynamically create a 2-level cascading menu with angular and material components.

- The first level is comprised of a md-nav-list with a bunch of
  md-list-items containing buttons created using ngFor
- The second level menu is an md-menu with buttons. The md-menu button are generated using a nested
- Now, I would like to trigger the second level menu when hovering on a first level element.

  ```
    ...

    // Level 1 Menu
    <button class="cq-but" md-menu-item *ngIf="item.type === 'sub'"
      [mdMenuTriggerFor]= ... // <- how do I reference mdMenu here??
       item.name
    </button>

    // Level 2 Menu
    <md-menu class="cq-popup" *ngIf="item.type === 'sub'" #subMenu="mdMenu" id=item.name>
      <button md-menu-item *ngFor="let childitem of item.children">
          childitem.name
      </button>
    </md-menu>


  </md-list-item>
  ```

**What I need help with**

The dyanmically generated md-menu needs to be triggered via a [mdMenuTriggerFor]in the buttons on the first level.

As I've noted in the code snippet above, my question is... how do I bind to the dynamically generated md-menu component in my mdMenuTriggerFor directive?

**What I have tried **
- I tried to get a reference to the subMenu using ViewChildren i.e.

```
// @ViewChildren('subMenu') public subMenu:QueryList<MdMenu>;
```

hoping to programmatically trigger the menu without having to provide the mdMenuTriggerFor directive in the template. However that does not work because according to https://material.angular.io/components/component/menu the mdMenuTriggerFor directive is necessary to attach the menu to a trigger element in the DOM

Open to other approaches. Thanks!

Comment: Vijay, did you get any successful aproach? I'm working on a project and I'm about to face a similar situation (in fact I've just post a question about it here). What I'm thinking: encapsulating the trigger and the md-menu in a component (the template reference variable is component scoped, so there will be no conflicts) and pass the necessary parameters to this component by using one-way data-binding. It's kind of late here in Brazil, but I intend to try it tomorrow.

Comment: It worked, Vijay. Take a look at my answer to my own question: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/44192485/6433166](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44192485/6433166)

Comment: Thanks jpavel. I can confirm that this approach has worked for me. 

Even with even with material 2.0.0-beta.12 we don't have a way to associate [matMenuTriggerFor] - previously [mdMenuTriggerFor], to a dynamic reference for matMenu. Encapsulating the trigger and mat-menu like you proposed does the trick.

Comment: Vlay, I suggested another way in the answer bellow.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it: you can use **`<ng-container>`** and it will just create a private scope for your template variable (https://stackblitz.com/edit/repeating-menu-approach-2):

```
<table class="table table-striped">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let el of [1,2,3,4,5]">
    <tr>
      <td>Text line of menu {{el}}</td>
      <td style="width: 5%">
        <button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">
          <mat-icon>more_vert</md-icon>
        </button>
        <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
          <button mat-menu-item (click)="clickHandler('Item 1 of Menu ' + el)">Menu {{el}}:Item 1</button>
          <button mat-menu-item (click)="clickHandler('Item 2 of Menu ' + el)">Menu {{el}}:Item 2</button>
        </mat-menu>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </ng-container>
</table>
```

Interestingly, each **`#menu`** template variable above will be unique, successfully isolated from the others **`#menu`** template variables created by the `*ngFor` loop.