# Angular Material 2 MatMenu - Dynamically creation

Tags: angular, angular-material

I need to dynamically create a bunch of `MatMenu`. So far I have no idea of how I can:

1 - Create a template reference variable dynamically (for the `mat-menu` component)

2 - Reference the dynamically created variable (to use in the `[matMenuTriggerFor]` attribute of the trigger)

I've searched a little and found nothing about it.

Does anyone manage do deal with it?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Solved by encapsulating the `MatMenu` and the associated trigger in an Angular custom component.

Scenario: There's an array of objects that must be shown in a table. The last column of the table must show the `MatMenu` with two options: Edit and Delete.

So I made a custom angular component containing just the `MatMenu` and its trigger inside it. This component uses two-way data bind to receives the object that must be edited/deleted and proceed with the desired action:

- If the purpose is to edit, shows a dialog to edit the data
- If the purpose is to delete, it deletes the data

Once the action is completed, the host of the custom component must perform one of two actions:

1 - update the array replacing/deleting the edited/removed element

2 - update the entire array, asking for all its forming data again from the server

In both cases, you'll have to monitor the changes and do any updates in the array whenever the update/deletion is finished. An alternative is to create another two-way data bound variable and pass the entire array as a two-way data-bound parameter to the custom component.

I built up this Stackblitz to better show it: https://stackblitz.com/edit/repeating-menu-approach-1

```
<table>
  <tr *ngFor="let el of [1,2,3,4,5]">
    <td>Text line of menu {{el}}</td>
    <td style="width: 5%">
      <menu-overview-example [x]="el" (clickedItem)="hostClickHandler($event)"></menu-overview-example>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

### Another approach

There's one more way to do it: you can use `<ng-container>` and it will just create a scope for your template variable (https://stackblitz.com/edit/repeating-menu-approach-2):**

```
<table>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let el of [1,2,3,4,5]">
    <tr>
      <td>Text line of menu {{el}}</td>
      <td style="width: 5%">
        <button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">
          <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
        </button>
        <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
          <button mat-menu-item (click)="clickHandler('Item 1 of Menu ' + el)">Menu {{el}}:Item 1</button>
          <button mat-menu-item (click)="clickHandler('Item 2 of Menu ' + el)">Menu {{el}}:Item 2</button>
        </mat-menu>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </ng-container>
</table>
```

Interestingly, each **`#menu`** template variable above will be unique, fully isolated from the others **`#menu`** template variables created by the `*ngFor` loop.

**[UPDATE]:** As a matter of fact, you can drop the `<ng-container>` and use the `*ngFor` directly on the `<tr>` element along with the `#menu` template variable. The isolated scope will be created in the same way as described above. But as I think it's more comprehensible for angular new users the presence of `ng-container`, I decided to keep it on this answer.

Comment: This solution is great for table with rows less than 50-100. With 1000 rows table becomes very slow because 1000 mat-menus will be created. @jpavel Can you make optimize it by creating mat-menu dynamically when vertical icon button clicked. I am trying to implement it, but, I don't know how to attach "matMenuTriggerFor" dynamically to vertical button.

Comment: @SagarYadav, try out the lazy loading feature:  https://material.angular.io/components/menu/overview#lazy-rendering. And let me know if it helped.

Comment: @jpavel it worked. Now my list has 1000+ items and it is loading very fast. Thank You.

Comment: I get the following for the `item` in the `*ngFor="let item of navItems"`.  `Can't bind to 'item' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-container`.  This is my issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57794412/angular-materials-cant-get-multi-items-to-work?noredirect=1#comment102023401_57794412