# Angular Html Variable Declaration with Interpolation

Tags: angular

I'm trying to build a navigation with possible multiple sub menus.

The problem is that I'm looping through the navigation items like this:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of navigationItems">
     <a>{{ item.path }}</a>
     <!-- sub menu goes here -->
  </li>
</ul>
```

Angular Material using the following syntax to enable the menu:

```
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
</mat-menu>
```

Now I'm looking for a way to use interpolation to make my menu variable unique like this:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of navigationItems">
     <a>{{ item.path }}</a>

     <!-- todo: add mat menu trigger -->

     <mat-menu #{{ item.path }}="matMenu">
       <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
       <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
     </mat-menu>

  </li>
</ul>
```

the most important part is this: `#{{ item.path }}="matMenu"`
is there any other solution? Thanks

Comment: I try to build the navigation dynamically. one navigation item could have an array of sub menu items and if i click on the item the correct submenu should appear

Comment: Ok so you want to know how to assign a _dynamic templateRef value_ for your mat-menu component. I'm not working with material but I checked for you, you can check [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/repeating-menu-approach-2) from [this SO's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44170543/angular-material-2-matmenu-dynamically-creation)

Comment: that's what I'm looking for. thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's definitely not possible to use interpolations in a template variable names:
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4581#issuecomment-148786554

Answer (score 0):

You can do something similar using `ViewChildren` and give all of them the same template name.

```
<mat-menu #menu>
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
</mat-menu>
```

Grab all instances of #menu in your component via `ViewChildren`.

```
@ViewChildren(‘menu’) private menus: QueryList<MatMenu>;
```

Then in your component simply map the items to an index and retrieve it that way.

```
public getMenuFor(item: Item): MatMenu {
  // Find the index for item
  const index = ...
  // Retrieve the MatMenu for index
  return this.menus.toArray()[index];
}
```